# javascript object access performance

Tags: javascript, performance, object, properties

In Javascript, when your getting a property of an object, is there a performance penalty to getting the whole object vs only getting a property of that object?

Also Keep in mind I'm not talking about DOM access these are pure simple Javascript objects.

For example:

Is there some kind of performance difference between the following code:

Assumed to be faster but not sure:

```
var length = some.object[key].length;

if(length === condition){
  // Do something that doesnt need anything inside of some.object[key]
}
else{
  var object = some.object[key];
  // Do something that requires stuff inside of some.object[key]
}
```

I think this would be slower but not sure if it matters.

```
var object = some.object[key];

if(object.length === condition){
  // Do something that doesnt need anything inside of some.object[key]
}
else{
  // Do something that requires stuff inside of some.object[key]
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Yes, there is a performance penalty.

The more deep is a property nested, more time will be required to perform the property lookup.

Check this [free chapter](http://yuiblog.com/assets/High_Perf_JavaScr_Ch2.pdf) of the book [High Performance JavaScript](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596802806), in the page 31, it talks specifically about Nested Members.

[image]

(Access time related to property depth)

See also this performance test:

- [JavaScript Data Access Test](http://www.nczonline.net/experiments/javascript/performance/data-access/)

Comment: link is dead and could it be updated with more recent browsers?

Comment: this link should work. https://www.nczonline.net/experiments/javascript/performance/data-access.html