# Is it always necessary for overlay elements to be located in end of HTML body?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position, overlay

I have noticed that in javascript frameworks elements such as dialogs, tooltips and alerts mostly appear at end of body.

I'm making my own implementation of these elements and trying to make it failproof. I'm repeating some techniques like using transparent iframe to overlay embeded objects in old browsers, and so on.

What restrictions could I face if I place my dialog/tooltip somewhere deep inside of the DOM tree with `{position: fixed}`? I'm afraid if there are some dangers to this approach, because big frameworks never use it.

I want to support IE8+.

Comment: Those elements are usually placed there because of z-ordering. The last element in the element tree is on top.

Comment: I agree, z-ordering is a consideration.. actually, node placement may also be a consideration.. that's, as a framework.. you don't want to imped on the cssstyledeclaration that users might use.. like `:nth-child()`.. or other implicit patterns developers and designers have gone with..

Comment: @Teemu you should post it as an answer, expanding the concept. BTW since she said it has fixed position, it should not matter that much, due to the element being stripped from the flow, isn't it ?

Comment: @AndreaLigios, it matters still...

Comment: It the same reason you put scripts at the end. If something is not shown first, should be placed last.

Comment: @Teemu Yes, last element of tree on top, but there always z-index management system in this frameworks besides that, so do I.

Comment: @lujcon it's not the same reason. You load scripts last so they don't block the page loading.

Comment: @lujcon, there are larger concerns as to why you put scripts at the end..

Comment: @nya Yes, but the implementation of `z-index` varies, you can't rely it to work in the same way in different browsers.

Comment: when you say deep inside.. you have to be aware of `overflow` and `position` declarations of all the parent containers..

Comment: @Teemu And that's why I start this topic, I want to know, why frameworks put it there. Maybe it because some ie6-7, that's I don't need.

Comment: @BrettCaswell Parent position and overflow affect node with position: fixed?

Comment: I put overlay data at the end of the dom because that info is usually specific to action or superfluous and I would rather it was not indexed redundantly within an article. For example, a "read more" in a modal popup. Or a login popup box. Neither of which need to be seen with any priority by search engines or subject to css inheritance. So dump them at the end to avoid both.

Comment: wait, nevermind.. I need to review that..

Comment: How about the fact that it's really easy to say document.body.appendChild(...)?

Comment: @bobdye, haha.. that's probably the most practical reason..

Comment: @bobdye That code will be performed inside framework. My point to use inside-popups is way to make independent blocks of HTML binded with JS instances, that will have access to such blocks inside of it, but necessary to have content of popups outside of it parent block is breaking that concept

Answer (score 2):

Aside from z-ordering that is a very valid point made by [Teemu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1169519/teemu), another major consideration in JS frameworks is speed of execution / speed of lookup.

The DOM in JS terms is one large object. The deeper into an object javascript needs to go to get what it's being asked for, the less performant the script gets, [take a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936807/javascript-object-access-performance).

Therefore it makes sense to keep everything that is probably going to be cloned or deep copied at a sensible nesting level and in the correct z-order. That happens to be toward the end of the body and usually wrapped by at most one containing element.

There may be other reasons but the depth / nesting sprung to mind as a consideration I'd take into account.

Comment: There's still no clear answer about z-ordering problems.
Also, not sure if tooltips/dialogs should be cloned from one to another, but not from special tooltips/dialog templates store.

Comment: Sure, not everything would need cloning but in terms of nesting it provides a convenient location for template / ready to use html. z-ordering is important for modals / tooltips etc. as they are 99.9% of the time required to show above all other content. Giving them naturally higher z-indexes by DOM location makes a lot of sense.

Comment: How much sense in natural leveling with such kind of z-index management http://puu.sh/fZYGP/36209d51cf.png ?
That is the question.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - very few techniques like this are "always necessary". JavaScript can easily remove items from their natural position in the DOM and relocate them at will.

Long answer - I don't think approaching this from a JavaScript first angle is correct. Look at it in terms of where the content belongs naturally within the hierarchy of the rest of the DOM.

For example, if you are talking about a modal dialog, then the chrome (the container elements) usually do not belong within the rest of the DOM - they exist only to contain and provide modal overlay functionality for the content within. This chrome does not participate in the outline of the DOM and the rest of the content. In that case, unless you are able to load them separately via ajax or embed the chrome HTML within the JavaScript, then the closest you will come to removing them from the main DOM is to append them to the bottom of the main DOM content. Note that this disregards the upcoming TEMPLATE element (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/) which is designed for just this purpose.

However, the **content** of your dialog might very well belong within the main content of the DOM - either as an element, or as an attribute (i.e. title or data-) to an associated element. This would especially be true for tooltip text.

Comment: I can easily move nodes to end of page when it's loaded, as frameworks do, but in my case I'm trying to use independent blocks of HTML, where each block contain all his stuff (including dialogs) all time of page life.