# Should we prefer Chai's `to.be.an('undefined')` vs `to.equal(undefined)`?

Tags: javascript, chai

Regrettably there is more than one way to do things in Chai.

Is there a benefit either way, to using  `to.be.an('undefined')` over `to.equal(undefined)`?

My intuition there would be a cost to reusing/recreating undefined. Our test runner gives times for individual tests and it seems like what matters more which runs first (on a test watch the second one is faster, but doing two separate runs means they both take ~2 seconds (full set up) ).

Comment: I can't think of any difference. Prefer the one you like more, I'd personally go with the second one

Comment: One benefit of `to.equal(undefined)` is that it is more readable IMO.

Comment: Personally, I prefer the Assert versions: `chai.assert.isUndefined(foo)`

Comment: I prefer `to.be.undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it really matters. The closest I manage to find to an answer was [this article](https://medium.com/@me_37286/yoni-goldberg-javascript-nodejs-testing-best-practices-2b98924c9347)

> In that sense, code the expectation in a human-like language, declarative BDD style using *expect* or *should* and not using custom code.

The author doesn't seem to draw a distinction between the two and even your testing says they're more-or-less equal.

I say go with whatever makes sense.

*Edit*:

Based on [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2936825/557019)

> The more deep is a property nested, more time will be required to perform the property lookup.

That would imply that `to.be.an('undefined')` would actually be slower than `to.equal(undefined)` due to the additional lookup, but IMO the `prototype` pollution that comes with it could give false positives.

Same conclusion as before really: go with what makes sense.